# AS3 Mouse down not working

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseevent

I have a button that has been added to the stage. When it is created, it moves into the visible area of the stage, and calls an activate function, which adds an event listener to it that looks for mouse down. For some reason, however, this does not work. Any ideas as to why? I've tried adding a listener to the object via the one that created it, but that doesn't work either.

```
    package menus {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.*;

public class MenuPlayButton extends MovieClip {
    private var _stageWidth, _stageHeight:int;
    private var comeInTimer:Timer;
    private var buttonSpeed:Number;

    public function MenuPlayButton(stageWidth:int, stageHeight:int) {
        _stageWidth = stageWidth;
        _stageHeight = stageHeight;

        alpha = 1;
        rescaleMe();
        repositionMe();
        comeIntoMenu();
    }

    private function rescaleMe():void {
        var oldWidth = this.width;
        var oldHeight = this.height;

        this.height = _stageHeight/10;
        this.width = (this.height * oldWidth) / oldHeight;
    }

    private function repositionMe():void {
        this.x = 0 - this.width;
        this.y = _stageHeight * 0.56;
    }

    private function comeIntoMenu():void {
        //Sets button's original speed
        buttonSpeed = _stageHeight / 40;

        //Adds timer that moves in the button
        comeInTimer = new Timer(10,0);
        comeInTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, comeInTimerListener);
        comeInTimer.start();
    }

    private function comeInTimerListener(e:TimerEvent):void {
        if(x < 0) {
            x += buttonSpeed;
            buttonSpeed *= 0.93;
        } else {
            x = 0;
            activate();
        }
    }

    private function activate():void {
        //Kills off timer
        comeInTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, comeInTimerListener);
        comeInTimer.stop();
        comeInTimer = null;
        this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clicked);
        trace("Button should be activated"); //This gets traced
    }

    function clicked(e:MouseEvent) {
        trace("Button pressed");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Weird, I don't see any troubles with this code. Consider tracing `this.stage`, `this.x` and `this.y` along with `Button should be activated`, it's possible that your button is off stage due to inavailability of stage during its creation. In that case, add `if (stage) init(); else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);` standard structure into the constructor, and relocate its code into `function init(e:Event=null):void {...}` where you can address stage and retrieve its `stageWidth` and `stageHeight` properties without constructor params.

Comment: I tried tracing the button, it gives proper results. However, when I try to trace Mouse.x, it gives me:menus\MenuPlayButton.as, Line 65 1120: Access of undefined property Mouse.

Comment: Wait a second... Without the tracing, the code works when I import display.* instead of just MovieClip! O_o

Comment: Actually, they work when I add the listener to the stage, but not the button...

Comment: Did you add the button to stage actually? Or maybe you add it to a container which has its `visible` at false, or `mouseChildren` set to false? This prevents mouse events to reach your button.

Comment: You solved it! Thanks so much! All I had to do was change AddChild to stage.AddChild, and it worked! :D

Answer (score 0):

First of all clicked function must be void! Try change the code to

This.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked):void;{

Then

Function clicked (e:MouseEvente.CLICK):void;{